# How to read single node value from xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

Hi i am trying to get value from xml but it shows node null.

Here is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd" xmlns="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/TestAPI2/Result.xsd">
  <data>
    <key>MailingGUID</key>
    <value>0aa2b2e3-7afa-4002-ab2f-9eb4cbe33ae7</value>
  </data>
  <data>
    <key>OrderRef</key>
    <value>52186</value>
  </data>
</result>
```

I want to get **"MailingGUID"**  value.

Here is the code that i have tried:

```
  private void readXML()
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        // You'll need to put the correct path to your xml file here
        xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XmlFile11.xml"));

        // Select a specific node
        XmlNode node = xml.SelectSingleNode("result/data/value");
        // Get its value
        string name = node.InnerText;


    }
```

Please tell me how i can get **MailingGUID** value.

Thanks

Comment: You're on the right track, the problem is with your XPath query. Have a look here: [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:**
I think there might be something wrong with your schemas, I removed references to them and your code worked fine. I tried this:

```
const string str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><result><data><key>MailingGUID</key><value>0aa2b2e3-7afa-4002-ab2f-9eb4cbe33ae7</value></data><data><key>OrderRef</key><value>52186</value></data></result>";
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(str);
xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/result/data/value").InnerText
```

Comment: XmlNode node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/result/data");
        // Get its value
        string name = node.InnerText;                                         this gives me error of object refrence..

Comment: why i am getting null.   here is code:                                private void readXML()
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
      
        xml.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml"));

        var node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/result/data");
        var s = node["value"].InnerText;

      
    }

Comment: Try to debug your code and see what values you have at specific times in runtime. Does xml.Load work, what is your xml variable set to after load. Try removing XSD references and see if it solves your problem (which would mean problems with the XSD schemas).

Comment: its working for me by removing XSD.can you tell me why XSD files create errors..and i have to do to solve this problem of XSD.

Comment: I cannot tell you what is wrong with your XSD. You will have to open them and find the errors in them. If you don´t know how to debug it yourself you can use validation tools such as this to validate your XML against your XSD - http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html

Comment: Hi Marcus can i remove data inside <result> tag by code.because i have lot xml files.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that programmatically. I would personally open all the XML files in VS2012 and use search all documents to replace (\<result[^\>]*\>) with <result> with regular expressions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();                   

      //Parsing of xml is done here
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\User_Name\\Documents\\My Received Files\\PDSL_ABM.xml"));

        //Here we get the root element of XML and print out
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("MailingGUID");
        int totalMailingGUID  =list.getLength();
        System.out.println("Total no of MailingGUID  : " + totalSupplierPartID);



      //Traversing all the elements from the list and printing out its data
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

      //Getting one node from the list.
        Node childNode = list.item(i);
        System.out.println("MailingGUID  : " + childNode.getTextContent());
        }
```