# Parsing XML with namespace using DOM

Tags: c#, xml

XML is small and looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><userdetails xsi:schemaLocation="urn:MyNamespace loginasp.xsd" xmlns="urn:MyNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><username>909</username><password>madhuri1</password></userdetails>
```

For parsing this XML i have written the below code.

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.LoadXml(s);//S contains above XML
 XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
                    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
 string emp_id = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/userdetails/username", nsmgr).InnerText;
```

I am not able to select the single NODE`xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/userdetails/username", nsmgr)` is `null` Is there any else i need to do to parse XML or My XML is wrong.Without namespace it works fine

Comment: Why -1 is there anything wrong ??

Comment: catch this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250671/how-to-read-single-node-value-from-xml-file

Comment: someone answer this question previously

Comment: That link doesn't actually answer the question although it is the same problem. It isn't to do with schemas, it's to do with changing the default namespace.

Comment: That link does not answer the probelm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your default namespace into the XmlNamespaceManager.

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("t", "urn:MyNamespace");
```

And then use this namespace in your XPath Query

```
string emp_id = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/t:userdetails/t:username", nsmgr).InnerText;
```