# How to get values from XML file based on Key field in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm new to XML. I have a file as below which lists the details of courses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESPONSE>
  <SINGLE>
    <KEY name="courses">
      <MULTIPLE>
        <SINGLE>
          <KEY name="id">
            <VALUE>3</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          <KEY name="category">
            <VALUE>6</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          <KEY name="shortname">
            <VALUE>XYZ101</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          <KEY name="fullname">
            <VALUE>BUS101: Introduction </VALUE>
          </KEY>
            <KEY name="description">
            <VALUE>This is a dummy text for description;</VALUE>
          </KEY>
        </SINGLE>
        <SINGLE>
          <KEY name="id">
            <VALUE>4</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          <KEY name="category">
            <VALUE>7</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          <KEY name="shortname">
            <VALUE>ABC101</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          <KEY name="fullname">
            <VALUE>ABC101: ABC Category</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          <KEY name="description">
            <VALUE>Detailed introduction to the basic principles and methods ;</VALUE>
          </KEY>
          </SINGLE>
</RESPONSE>
```

I want to read this file and display the contents as below in asp page, please help. I tried the example from [How to read single node value from xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250671/how-to-read-single-node-value-from-xml-file). But it didn't return any value. My expected output is as below
Id, category, shortname, fullname,                  description
3,    6 ,      XYZ101,   BUS101: Introduction,      This is a dummy text for description
4,    7,       ABC101,   ABC101: ABC Category,      Detailed introduction to ...

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct mapping and not just copy and paste code from URL? Btw, your XML doesn't look good. Can you check tags single/key/multiple?

Comment: The xml is created by a webservice to pull the course details from moodle.

Comment: I mean did you copied all elements from source? Because I do not see closing tags for mentioned nodes

Comment: Sorry, I've copied only few lines here as sample from the original xml file because its a large file.

Comment: Can you share your code till now?

Comment: Meanwhile I tried another method using Linq as below , in this case the nodename returns each line in the xml (eg.SINGLE) and the nodeval returns all values under that node irrespective of the node.                   public void loaddata()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

         XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("~/App_Data/Contents.xml");

        var allElements = doc.Descendants();

        foreach (XElement el in allElements)
        {
            var nodename = el.Name;
            var nodeval = el.Value;
            
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may give a try to following using XDocument:

```
XDocument doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(yourXMLFile);
            var ab = doc.Root.Descendants("SINGLE").Descendants("KEY").Descendants("MULTIPLE").Descendants("SINGLE").Select(x => new { values = x.Elements().ToList() }).ToList();
            var newList = ab.Select(y => new
            {
                values = y.values.Select(z =>
                    new
                    {
                        key = z.Attribute("name").Value,
                        value = z.Elements("VALUE").FirstOrDefault().Value
                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

It will give you the xml nodes with id, category etc.

Comment: Got it! Thanks kashi_rock  for your help. Have a great day!

Comment: I appreciate if you could help me to load the contents of the list to a gridview.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-GridView-with-Generic-List-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx